# create insert if not exist in mysql

Tags: mysql

In MySql we can choose `INSERT IGNORE(do not update existing)` to generate a sql file with query `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` and  `INSERT IGNORE INTO`.

But in this case,if the table exists, the "INSERT IGNORE INTO" will insert data again.
   I'd like to ask,is there a method, to realize the function: If table doesn't exist, it will create the table and insert data.

If the table exists, it will not insert data.

In fact I have tried how to realize, I know with a stored procedure it is possible, but with a sql file which will be executed by batch file, how to realize the function?

My curent code is like this

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS martintest;

USE martintest; 
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `martin1` (
  `col1` int(11) default NULL,
  `col2` text
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT IGNORE INTO `martin1` (`col1`, `col2`) VALUES    (2, 'bbb'), (1, 'aaa');
```

Comment: Does the table have a primary key?

Comment: yes.there is a primary key

Comment: Can you add some SQL or even better a SQL fiddle, then I can help you better?

Comment: but the problem is,suppose in the database there is one records,in the sql file,if there is a record which does not existed in the the database,if will be insersted.however, my requirement is,as long as the table exists,no record would be inserted. Thank u very much for ur kindness reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option, perhaps not recommended (one must be careful with session variables, in this case, with: `` @`table_exists?` ``), but an option in the end, is something like:

```sql
/* CODE FOR DEMONSTRATION PURPOSES */

USE `martintest`;

SET @`table_schema` := 'martintest', @`table_name` := 'martin1';

SELECT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT NULL
        FROM `information_schema`.`TABLES` `ist`
        WHERE `ist`.`TABLE_SCHEMA` = @`table_schema` AND `ist`.`TABLE_NAME` = @`table_name`
    )
INTO @`table_exists?`;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `martin1` (
  `col1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col2` text
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `martin1` SELECT 2, 'bbb' FROM DUAL WHERE 0 = @`table_exists?`;
INSERT INTO `martin1` SELECT 1, 'aaa' FROM DUAL WHERE 0 = @`table_exists?`;

/* CODE FOR DEMONSTRATION PURPOSES */
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CREATE TABLE without IF NOT EXISTS.
If the table exists, it will fail and the rest of the file will not be imported .

Do not use --force parameter,.

Comment: I actually hate this and this question screams 'bad design' but this is probably the way, +1.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the table exists first:

```
USE martintest; 
SET @tablecount := 0

SELECT @tablecount := count(*)
INTO @tablecount
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'martintest'
AND table_name = 'martin1'

--check if table count = 0
IF @tablecount = 0
(

CREATE TABLE `martin1` (
  `col1` int(11) default NULL,
  `col2` text
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `martin1` (`col1`, `col2`) VALUES    (2, 'bbb'), (1, 'aaa');

)
```

Comment: hi thank u. but to realze "IF ELSE",it must be in a stored procedure,right?

Comment: Guess not, it can probably also be used in queries.